# displaying a variable with vue js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to display the variable "stage" in the "{{ stageTest }} but I cannot seem to get it working. How do I go about displaying the variable with .vue? I have an alert box working so I know I am getting the result I just cant display it for some reason with .vue any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<div>{{ stageTest }}</div>
```

```js
test() {
  CONTRACT.name1(function (err, res) {
    var stage = res;
    alert(stage);
    this.stageTest = stage;
  })
}
```

Comment: you defined stageTest in your component's data option?

Comment: yes i did like this right export default {
  data () {
    return {
      stageTest: null
    }
  },

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the fact that when using the callback function with the `function` keyword you unbind what `this` refers to.

```js
test() {
  CONTRACT.name1((err, res) => { // Arrow functions unbind `this`
    var stage = res;
    alert(stage);
    this.stageTest = stage;
  })
}
```

I replaced your function with an arrow function, which unbinds the `this` keyword, so you still have the `this` from the upper scope.